# Dynamically add $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have a JSON dataset that each row includes an input value, a small block of JavaScript code used to calculate and a subtotal value that is the result of the input value after an eval() preforms the calculation.  The dataset will contain one or more rows.  Each input will be repeated onto the page in HTML and a sum of the subtotals will be shown to the user as a total value along with each separate subtotal value.

I tried to use $watch and add one for each row in the repeater but I can't seem to get them to fire as the user changes the input value.

I have created my first [Sample_Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MNTEeY12UDP0rERn0w6s)  to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve with no success.

Not sure if I should also be posting the code here or not but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Basically my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as MainCtrl" ng-init="MainCtrl.init()">
    <div ng-repeat="rule in MainCtrl.myCode">

        Input_{{$index}}: <input ng-model="rule.inpValue" type="number" />
        <!-- the following needs to reflect the result after eval() of myCode[?].code from JSON below -->
        Subtotal: {{rule.nSubTotal}}
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />

    <!-- the following should be a sum of all values above -->
    Total: {{MainCtrl.nTotal}}

</div>
```

This is my sample data and $watch that is not responding:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.nTotal = 0;
    // sample js code tht will be execuited later
    _this.myCode = [{
        "code": "_this.myCode.inpValue +2",
        "inpValue": 0,
        "nSubTotal": 0
    }, {
        "code": "_this.myCode.inpValue*3",
        "inpValue": 0,
        "nSubTotal": 0
    }, {
        "code": "_this.myCode.inpValue/5",
        "inpValue": 0,
        "nSubTotal": 0
    }];

    this.init = function() {
        $scope.$watch('MainCtrl.myCode[i].inpValue', function() {
            // debugger;

            // assuming if watch would fire, subtotal = eval( input ) 
            _this.nSubTotal = eval(_this.myCode[i].code);

            // I would also keep a running total at this point
            _this.nTotal = _this.nTotal + _this.myCode[i].nSubTotal;
        });
    }; //end init()
});
```

Comment: Your watch is not firing because there is no property `i` on the `$scope` against which the watch expression is being evaluated. Can you please explain more about the dataset? Why do you need those JS code snippets? From what I see, they aren't even valid. `_this.myCode.inpValue` will resolve to undefined since `_this.myCode` is an array.

Comment: there is no wildcard `[i]` to make your watch work. Also your logic inside watch isn't going to keep proper track of total. Using `eval` like this looks really dangerous and really doesn't make much sense. There are cleaner ways to do the modifiers using 2 properties and no `eval`

Comment: Igor: the code snippets are part of a shopping cart system but not like anything I've ever seen before.  There are hosts who are a fairly fixed group of around 800 (think of these as companies).  Each of the hosts has 1 or more checkout rules that apply to their customers.  There about 150 customers per host.  The host can create the rules (code snippets) and assign them to each of their customer. so to hard code all these rules into the source, I think fetching the rules from data is a much better way to handle a matrix of this size. And to maintain it, I only have revise the data.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot wrong with your code, but basically to answer your question, you can apply a watch to each of the items in an array by looping through the array and calling `$scope.$watch` once for each element.

I also strongly advise you to use actual functions and not `eval()` in order to evaluate expressions.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var _this = this;
  _this.nTotal = 0;

  // sample js code tht will be execuited later
  _this.myCode = [{
    "code": function() { return this.inpValue + 2; },
    "inpValue": 0,
    "nSubTotal": 0
  }, {
    "code": function() { return this.inpValue * 3; },
    "inpValue": 0,
    "nSubTotal": 0
  }, {
    "code": function() { return this.inpValue / 5; },
    "inpValue": 0,
    "nSubTotal": 0
  }];

  function sum (values) {
      return values.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
  }

  this.init = function() {

    _this.myCode.forEach(function(code) {
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return code.inpValue;
      }, function() {
        code.nSubTotal = code.code();
        _this.nTotal = sum(_this.myCode.map(function(c) { return c.nSubTotal; }));
      });
    });

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.7" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as MainCtrl" ng-init="MainCtrl.init()">
  <div ng-repeat="rule in MainCtrl.myCode">

    Input_{{$index}}:
    <input ng-model="rule.inpValue" type="number" />

    Subtotal: {{rule.nSubTotal}}
    <br />

  </div>
  <br />

  <!-- the following should be a sum of all values above -->
  Total: {{MainCtrl.nTotal}}

  <br />
  <br />

</div>
```

Comment: What is so wrong with eval()?  I was thinking the eval would be wrapped by a try/catch.  And the code that is stored in the JSON would have been pretested before it ever goes live.

Your answer offers a lot of new things to me, never used map or reduce - very cool!  And I'm still trying to understand what you have done but it sure looks simple and straight forward.  **Brilliant** - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$watch` is not firing because you are watching an expression which will always evaluated to `undefined` against the `$scope`. You have a few options when it comes to watching a set of items for changes:

1. A separate `$watch` for each item. Not very efficient, especially if the array is large.
2. A `$watchGroup`, which accepts an array of watch expressions. Useful when the expressions are non-uniform, for example different properties of different objects.
3. A `$watchCollection`, which shallow-watches a single object. I think this works best for your situation.

Also, note that the first argument to `$watch*` can be a function which returns a value you would like to watch. Putting this together, your watcher can look like

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
  var aInputs = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = myCode.length; i < len; ++i) {
    aInputs.push(myCode[i].inpValue);
  }
  return aInputs;
}, function() {
  // one of the inpValues in myCode has changed
  // need to re-compute nTotal
});
```

Also, I strongly recommend you do not use `eval()` and follow JLRishe's suggestion of using functions. If you absolutely need to evaluate string expressions, you can do this safely with Angular's `$scope.$eval`. This evaluates expressions against a scope and a set of local variables. For example,

```
$scope.$eval("inpValue + 2", { inpValue: 3 }) === 5;
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkqZ7FcNBy2yLOwvZqRu?p=preview). It uses `$eval` as a proof of concept, but again, if you can, use plain functions.