# Dynamically adding watchers to inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a dynamic form renderer which gets a list of fields from a database and renders them so the user can input data and send it to the database.

Right now im adding the functionality to set evaluations to fields that have options, making it give a number base evaluation depending on the option select by the user.

```
/* load fields from database
the result looks like $scope.fields = [{field_name: "dishes", 
input_type:  "radio", options:["{number: 20, value: 'tuna'}",
"{number: 30, value:'salmon'}"], id: "id1", is_evaluated: true }]
i know the watcher wont look into dict info so that's why i keep the
option dicts as strings
(i dont really remember the correct JSONparse syntax but assume i wrote
those dicts correctly)
*/
watchers = [];
for(field in $scope.fields){
    if($scope.fields[field].is_evaluted == true){//there can be fields which don't have numeric evaluation
        watchers.push($scope.$watch(function(){
            return $scope.values[$scope.fields[field].id];
        },
        function(){
            console.log("watcher triggered");
            console.log("new value is:" + JSON.parse($scope.values[$scope.fields[field].id]).value)
        });
    }
}
```

where the $scope.values is a dict with it's keys as the field ids which keeps the options selected, the option value is needed for database processing and the "number" is the numeric evaluation which will we used for html display(those console.logs will actually be the jquery/angular code to display the evaluation)
Note: there can be field which are not evaluated

everything seems good till i try the application and well, only the last evaluated field  is watched (like i add 9 evaluated fields, 3 non evaluated fields and all the watchers trigger on the same field)

Note2: i already saw this [Dynamically add $watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311105/dynamically-add-watch) question which gave me this idea, sadly i couldn't use the exact save code for 2 reasons 1: they use array and i use dict, 2: they care about the input value while i only want to see it change so i can use the other value

So what should i change? why all the watchers look the last variable instead of the one i wanted to give them?
any help will be really appreciated

my html is like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <ng-if="field.input_type == 'radio'">
        <ng-repeat="option in field.options">
            <input type="radio" value={{option}} ng-model="$scope.Values[field.id]">{{option.value}}</ng-if>
        </ng-repeat>
    </ng-if>
</div>
```

there is a lot more html in this...(like for each type of input but radio
is perfect example for evaluated fields) That would render two radio inputs
one saying tuna and the other saying salmon, so when i choose salmon i want to display the 30 points i get and when i switch to tuna i want to display the 20

Comment: it may or may not be exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but there is already an extensive project for creating forms from JSON schema documents.  http://schemaform.io/.  even if you can't use the project as is, it likely has code you can borrow from, since it seems to do the same kind of task you are asking about.

Comment: i checked that proyect, it seems exactly the same thing I already made, im just trying to expand this, like when i change my ng-model i wanted another variable to be changed too, but i don't remember why ng-change wasn't the correct answer to my problem, thanks anyways